# PHP Advanced search - multiple parameters

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm working on a advanced search function:

```
$colname_SokvansterImp = "-1"; 

mysql_select_db($database_Audiologiska, $Audiologiska);
if (isset($_POST['Personnummer_search'])) 
{   
    //Visa bara det som söks
     $searchword = $_POST['Personnummer_search'];
    $query_SokvansterImp = "SELECT * FROM patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.Patv = patient.Patient WHERE vanster_implantat.patv LIKE '%".$searchword."%'";

}
else//Visa all data
{

    $query_SokvansterImp = "select * from patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.patv = patient.Patient";

}
$SokvansterImp = mysql_query($query_SokvansterImp, $Audiologiska) or die(mysql_error());
$row_SokvansterImp = mysql_fetch_assoc($SokvansterImp);
$totalRows_SokvansterImp = mysql_num_rows($SokvansterImp);
```

This is working for searching with one parameters, however, I'm wondering how to make it accepts multiple parameters? "Personnummer_search" is the name of my field. How can I make so it can search for example Name and/or Surname? I'm using Dreamweaver

Comment: Dreamweaver has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver to this. I can update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new conditional block ?

```
if (isset($_POST['Personnummer_search'])) 
{   
    //Visa bara det som söks
     $searchword = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Personnummer_search']);
    $query_SokvansterImp = "SELECT * FROM patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.Patv = patient.Patient WHERE vanster_implantat.patv LIKE '%".$searchword."%'";

}
else if(isset($_POST['Name_search']) && isset($_POST['Surname_search']))
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Name_search']);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string(($_POST['Surname_search']);
    $query_SokvansterImp = "YOUR SQL QUERY...";

}
else//Visa all data
{
    $query_SokvansterImp = "select * from patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.patv = patient.Patient";
}
```

Comment: Well, then just use $mysqli->real_escape_string()... I don't think the question was about this...

Comment: I guess I am a little biased.

Comment: No, you're right... just didn't took this into account. I'm editing the answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear in my question but your solution would not work because I want it to be able to search for one or multiple parameters and your "If, else if statement" will only run one of the queries but not both

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to search for all possible filters, you can do:

```
$where = array();

if (isset($_POST['Personnummer_search'])) 
{   
    $searchword = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Personnummer_search']);
    $where[] =  "vanster_implantat.patv LIKE '%".$searchword."%'";
}

if(isset($_POST['Name_search']))
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Name_search']);
    $where[] =  "nameField LIKE '%".$name."%'";

}

if(isset($_POST['Surname_search']))
{
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Name_search']);
    $where[] =  "surnameField LIKE '%".$surname."%'";

}

if(count($where))
{
   $query_SokvansterImp = "SELECT * FROM patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient
    left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.Patv = patient.Patient
     WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$where);
}
else//Visa all data
{
    $query_SokvansterImp = "select * from patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.patv = patient.Patient";
}
```

Comment: It didn't return any result

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PHP Site, There is a function called "func_get_args"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php