# Advanced search requiring multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a advanced search function but can't get it to return any values.

```
mysql_select_db($database_Audiologiska, $Audiologiska);
$where = array();
if (isset($_POST['Personnummer_search'])) 
{   
    $searchword = $_POST['Personnummer_search'];
    $where[] =  "vanster_implantat.patv LIKE '%".$searchword."%'";
}
if(isset($_POST['Namn_search']))
{
    $name = $_POST['Namn_search'];
    $where[] =  "person.Namn LIKE '%".$name."%'";

}
if(isset($_POST['Efternamn_search']))
{
    $surname = $_POST['Efternamn_search'];
    $where[] =  "person.Efternamn LIKE '%".$surname."%'";

}
if(count($where))
{
   $query_SokvansterImp = "SELECT * FROM patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient
    left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.Patv = patient.Patient
     WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$where);
}
else//Visa all data
{

    $query_SokvansterImp = "select * from patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.patv = patient.Patient";

}
$SokvansterImp = mysql_query($query_SokvansterImp, $Audiologiska) or die(mysql_error());
$row_SokvansterImp = mysql_fetch_assoc($SokvansterImp);
$totalRows_SokvansterImp = mysql_num_rows($SokvansterImp);
```

Can you see if there is anything wrong with this code (except that it's not mysqli instead of mysql)?

Comment: echo `$query_SokvansterImp` and put the output in here.

Comment: This is when i filled in "Personnummer" but not the other fields:
SELECT * FROM patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.Patv = patient.Patient WHERE vanster_implantat.patv LIKE '%19920506%' AND person.Namn LIKE '%%' AND person.Efternamn LIKE '%%'

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities with this code - to see how to protect against this, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25108445/472495) to your very similar earlier question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried manually running that query; e.g. using the mysql command line tool or phpMyAdmin?

If you do, then you should get feedback on any potential errors, typos etc...

Also - just to be clear, do you actually perform `mysql_query()` on the query string, and `mysql_fetch_array/fetch_row/fetch_assoc()`?
Should look something like this:

```
    $result = mysql_query($query_SokvansterImp) or die(mysql_error());
    // die(mysql_error()); will cause the script to stop executing on error, 
    //and display the error message - you can leave it out but it's useful for debugging...

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // Do stuff with the returned data - can be referenced by result column name
    }
```

### EDIT after comment #3:

Try swapping `isset()` in the conditions of your if-statements with `if ($value != '')`. 
It may be that the values are set (causing `isset()` to return true) even if there's no real text there...

Comment: i didn't show all the code, just the code that connects to the database. I'm using phpmyAdmin and Dreamwewaver. I will update my answer

Comment: Does the query produce the correct (expected) results if you run it in phpMyAdmin? If so, I'd just try adding 'or die()'s everywhere it may fail (mysql_connect(), mysql_select_db() etc...) and see how far it gets...

Comment: No. it dosent work on phpmyadmin either. The problem is "AND person.Namn LIKE '%%' AND person.Efternamn LIKE '%%'" It has to be someway around it..

Comment: Do you mean like this? if ($value != 'Personnummer_search')

Comment: No, more like if($_POST['Personnummer_search'] != '')